# Android: How can I transfer an app with all of its storage data (not just apk) to PC?

Tags: android, apk, dex

**(PROBLEM)**

I want to transfer an app that according to the storage tab in my settings has 5gb (the app requires you to download a lot of files after initially installing it), but every app that I've tried (like Syncios for example) has only given me access to the 80mb apk, without any dex files. The iTools app that I used back when I had an iOS device would always transfer the entirety of an app's files from the get-go, so I am really in the dark about what the issue could be.

*(context)*

*I wanted to make an online community revolving around a fairly obscure mobile game, which means that I need some game assets to make it look nice. I had a very consistent way of doing that with iOS apps, but now that I've switched to android, nothing I do seems to work.*

Comment: I'd have a look at the [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) in [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio). You'll need to [enable developer mode and USB debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options), I think.

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you! Oh, and I have USB dsbugging enabled already :)

Comment: ok, so I can't really find anything this way... Any files relating to the game that I can find aren't debuggable or something...